# Saved render frame not same as Blender render preview

Tags: rendering, transparency

I’m trying to render an house xRay scan animation on transparent alpha background,
When i’m rendering it, everything looks good in the render window but when i look at my frames file, all the frames are empty (full alpha).

I tryed to render single frame and save it manually but the issue is still the same.
I link you the screenshot of the setup.
[image]

Hope someone knows a solution.
Thanks a lot !

EDIT : I saw a topic talking about PNG format not supporting emissive and transparency pixels. It suggest to render it in EXR format but the problem is still the same... Maybe the solution is near to this.

Comment: You could just render with black background and then use the image in screen blend mode or add blend mode to make the blacks be transparent